# How delete inf value in may output using python

Tags: python

I have this code:

```
Import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import math
import numpy as np
import numpy as geek
import itertools 
from itertools import permutations
from itertools import combinations
import collections
from math import sin
from math import asin
from math import pi



a= 1
b= 1
c= 1
alpha=90
beta=90
gamma=90
w=0.5 #width of your peak
basisatom =1;
p=1;
lamda=0.71073

x = [i for i in range(-1, 1, 1)]
y = [i for i in range(-1, 1, 1)]
z = [i for i in range(-1, 1, 1)]

all_list = [x,y,z]

res = np.array(list(itertools.product(*all_list)))

res1 = res.transpose()

a1= res1[0]
b1 = res1[1]
c1  = res1[2]
test_list = [a1,b1,c1]

for h, k, l in zip(*test_list):
    a1 =[h, k, l]
    aa1 = abs(np.array((a1)))
    ax =aa1[0]
    ay =aa1[1]
    az =aa1[2]
    
    V = (a*b*c)*geek.sqrt(1 - (math.cos(alpha))**2 - (math.cos(beta))**2 - (math.cos(gamma))**2 +2*((math.cos(alpha))*(math.cos(beta))*(math.cos(gamma))))
    Spp =( b**2)*(c**2)*((math.sin(alpha))**2)
    Sww = (a**2)*(c**2)*((math.sin(beta))**2)
    Snn = (a**2)*(b**2)*((math.sin(gamma))**2);
    Spw = (c**2)*b*a*((math.cos(alpha))*math.cos(beta)-math.cos(gamma))
    Swn = ((a**2)*b*c*(math.cos(beta))*(math.cos(gamma))-math.cos(alpha))
    Spn = (b**2)*a*c*((math.cos(gamma))*math.cos(alpha) - math.cos(beta))
    d = (geek.sqrt(((V**2)/(((Spp*(ax**2)) + Sww*(ay**2) + Snn*(az**2) + 2*(Spw*(ax*ay) + 2*(Swn*(ay*az)) + 2*Spn*(ax*az)))))))
    za = lamda/(2*d)
    print(d)
```

And the Output are:

0.15654653048738001
0.2742138334664101
0.22787361381000193
0.5219919198195865
0.22787361381000193
0.5219919198195865
0.5219919198195865
inf

I want to remove inf value in my array. I tried this code:

```
d = d.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan)
```

however, an error occurred.

AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'replace'

Is there any other way to remove the inf value? Thanks!

Comment: Can you add the code that you add to remove the inf value and the content of the error also?

Comment: please check the updated questions.

Comment: first line of `import` is written in `Import`(in uppercase)

Answer (score 1):

Your variable `d` is a float64, so you can't use the method `replace()`. You can just use an if condition at the end of the `for` loop:

```
    if d!=np.inf:
        za = lamda/(2*d)
        print(d)
```

Answer (score 1):

to remove `np.inf` from your array you can use a simple list comprehension as like in here:

```
import numpy as np
a = [0.15654653048738001, np.inf, 0.2742138334664101, 0.22787361381000193, 0.5219919198195865, 0.22787361381000193, 0.5219919198195865, 0.5219919198195865, np.inf]
filtered = [item for item in a if item!=np.inf]
print(filtered)
```

this will filter all appearances of np.inf and the output will be:

```
[0.15654653048738001, 0.2742138334664101, 0.22787361381000193, 0.5219919198195865, 0.22787361381000193, 0.5219919198195865, 0.5219919198195865]
```